# JTA transaction support for JBoss data grid in remote mode

Tags: caching, jboss, jta, infinispan

I am setting jboss data grid in remote client server mode. Entities in cache are hardly updated but retrieved frequently as it is all master data for my application. I am loading the cache with master data from database on application startup. when the entities are updated from application, I want to ensure these are updated in database and grid in one transaction. Is it possible in remote mode?
I have read in documents that JTA transactions are only supported in JBoss Data Grid's Library Mode.

If operation is not possible in single transaction whats is the best way to ensure consistency between data grid cache entities and database?

Comment: If you use Hibernate/JPA, there is an Infinispan second level cache implementation available, but only for embedded mode (where app and cache live in same JVM).

Comment: I can not use it in embedded mode because cache is shared between multiple applications. and these apps are installed on separate JBoss EAP clusters.

Comment: Why does the cache have to be shared? Can each application have its own cache and see how that goes? I don't see what is the problem you are trying to solve here... :\

Comment: @galder cache is loaded from database tables which are shared between both applications where one of the application can modify the data. If I keep separate cache then updates done by one application will not be available in other application cache.

Comment: Ok, I understand your situation. I don't know what your runtime is, but if it's Wildfly or JBoss Application Server, each Hibernate cache has the deployment archive name as part of the name, so even if there was a remote version, each app would have its own caches. At the end of the day, each app could have slightly different class versions... Personally, I'd stay with embedded cache but create a service that exclusively deals with the database, and have the 2 apps communicate with it. That way you don't have to start figuring out cache consistency issues between two apps.